# Java method call overloading logic

Tags: java, jvm, overloading

For the following code why does it print A, B? I would expect it to print B, B.
Also, does the method call performed by the JVM is evaluated dynamically or statically?

```
public class Main {
    class A {

    }

    class B extends A {

    }

    public void call(A a) {
        System.out.println("I'm A");
    }

    public void call(B a) {
        System.out.println("I'm B");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main m = new Main();
        m.runTest();
    }

    void runTest() {
        A a = new B();
        B b = new B();

        call(a);
        call(b);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Overloading is determined *statically* by the compiler. *Overriding* is done at execution time, but that isn't a factor here.

The static type of `a` is A, so the first method call is resolved to `call(A a)`.

Comment: Thank you, so what is evaluated dynamically?

Comment: @Maxim Veksler: Overriding - that is determined by the *actual* type of the target object, rather than the compile-time type.

Answer (score 3):

Since your object is known by its type `A` at that moment, the method with argument `A` is invoked. So yes, it's determined *statically*.

That's in order to avoid ambiguities. Your `B` is also an `A` - but both methods can't be invoked at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

`B` is a subclass of `A`. Since you instanciate a `B`, but assign it to a variable typed `A`, all `B` specifics will be 'lost', hence `call(a)` will be dispatched to `call(A, a)` and print 'A'.

Comment: That's a bit misleading.  The object called `a` still retains "all of its `B` specifics" - calling `a.getClass().getSimpleName()` for example would return "B".  It's just that as Jon pointed out, the overload is determined by the type of the **reference**, at compile time.  The compiler doesn't "know" in this context that `a` is actually an instance of `B`, so it compiles the call to the `call(A a)` method.  But `a` still *is* an instance of `B`.