# Will library overloaded method be used without recompiling?

Tags: java, classloader, overloading

Say there was a method in the library

```
public static <E> void doSmth(Collection<E> foo, Collection<E> bar){...}
```

and it was used in the following code:

```
Set<Object> foo = ...;
List<Object> bar = ...;
doSmth(foo, bar);
```

Now another version of library substitues the former in the classpath and it has two methods:

```
public static <E> void doSmth(Collection<E> foo, Collecion<E> bar){...}
public static <E> void doSmth(Set<E> foo, List<E> bar){...}
```

The application is not recompiled and run. Which method will be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overload resolution is a compile-time process, therefore its result can't change without recompilation.

So,

```
public static <E> void doSmth(Collection<E> foo, Collecion<E> bar){...}
```

will be used, since its signature is specified in the compiled file.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.9 - is it so only for static methods and not for instance methods?

Comment: @Ivan: Overloading resolution is applied to both static and instance methods in the same way. If you mean the last line of the section, it's about the case when method whose signature was choosen by overload resolution is overriden.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 versions of the same library in the classpath it's hard to tell which one would the classloader load first (and therefore which one it would use) -- in fact chances are results will differ from machine to machine and JVM to JVM.
If you do need a certain version to be loaded first, you can add it to the **bootclasspath** via `-Xbootclasspath` parameter in the command line.

Comment: No, only one version of library in the classpath. First - during compilation and first run. Second - during the second run.

Comment: So the second version of the library only appears after the second run? How? :O

Answer (score 1):

A library does not contains *methods*, classes do. And classes are loaded by classloader when they are needed the first time.

Classes are (usually) loaded in the same order as they appear on the classpath. *Usually* just because fancy custom classloaders can implement other strategies.

So to your question, and looking at *normal* behaviour: If we have two *classes* with the same name on the path, one contains two, the other one method, then only one class is loaded, which is the one, that the classloaders finds first. Once a class is loaded, there's no need for (the same) classloader to look for a class with the same name again.

---

[Overloading is determined statically at compile time, so method 1 will (still) be called.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006448/java-method-call-overloading-logic/2006455#2006455)

Comment: I'm very sorry the for the words "another version of library appears in the classpath". That was not what I meant.

Comment: @Ivan - got it and enhanced the answer ;)