# Why does the cast determine which overloaded method gets called?

Tags: java

If java is pass-by-value, and that value is the memory address for the actual type, then why does the overloaded method that's called get decided by the reference/declared type?

```
class Boss {

  void test(Object o){
    System.out.println("object"); 
  }

  void test(Boss b){ 
    System.out.println("boss"); 
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Boss b = new Boss();
    b.test((Object)b); //prints out object, why?
  }

}
```

Comment: What else should determine what method gets called? The result of the cast is a reference of type `Object` as far as the JVM is concerned.

Comment: The value that gets passed in, which is the memory address for a Boss object.
Therefore, I'd expect the actual type to determine which method gets called.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006448/java-method-call-overloading-logic - first related question, Jon Skeet answer...

Comment: Ever heard of C pointers? `int *myIntVar = malloc(sizeof(int)); void *myVoidPtr = myIntVar;` After that, there is no way to say for sure what type of the value at the address contained in `myVoidPtr` is without looking at `myIntVar`. @KacyRaye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic binding applies to the object on which the method is called, not to its parameters and method overloading.

In this case, the method is determined at compile time to be void test(Object o), because that's the overload that matches the argument types.

At run time, the implementation of `test(Object o)` is chosen based on the object on which it's called. In this case, that's the implementation in Boss.

As an example, say you had had done this:

```
class Director extends Boss { ... }.

Boss d = new Director();
Boss b = new Boss;
d.test((Object)b);
```

Then in terms of method overloading, the method chosen at compile time would still be `test(Object o)`. At runtime, the implementation could be in Director, because d references a Director.

Comment: Ugh...okay I'm frustrated with trying to edit my response so I just deleted it entirely.

If the overloaded method to be used is decided at compile time, then how do you explain when the compiler determines the method to be used is in a superclass?
But then changes the method to be used at run-time based on the actual type.
For example, if had a superclass SuperBoss with the same methods, and then had the following in main:
`SuperBoss b = new Boss();`
`b.test((Object)b);`

Comment: Oh, you know what? Ignore my previous comment.
You answered it already perfectly :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Overloading is decided at the compile time i.e the compiler decides which method to execute right during compilation, irrespective of the object that would be passed to it at runtime.  And since you are passing a reference variable of `Object` and not `Boss`, although the object is of `Boss`, it executes the overloaded `void test(Object b)` method.