# How to call overload method in java

Tags: java

```
public class OverLoad {

    void method(Integer i){
        System.out.println("Integer "+i);
    }
    void method(int i){
        System.out.println("in "+i);
    }
    public static void main(String a[]){
        OverLoad m= new OverLoad();
        m.method(2); //it calls method(int i) why?    
    }
}
```

If i call the `m.method(3)` it will call the int method why?
If i call the `m.method((Integer)3)` then it will call the Integer method.

By default it going into primitive data type

Comment: `3` is a literal primitive, so the `int` signature is a perfect match.

Comment: can you please explain more?

Comment: The Integer one needs autoboxing if you pass an int. So the int one is closer to the parameter you pass. When you pass an Integer, the int method would need auto unboxing, so the Integer one is closer to what you pass.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java method call overloading logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006448/java-method-call-overloading-logic)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> By default it going into primitive data type

Well yes, because that's the exact type of the argument. The type of the literal `2` is `int`, not `Integer` ([JLS 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)). It's convertible to `Integer` via a boxing conversion ([JLS 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)), but that will only happen if it's actually needed.

Overloading in Java occurs in three phases, as per [JLS 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

> The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.

So `m.method(2)` matches `method(int)` in the first phase, so doesn't need to proceed to the second phase.

Answer (score 6):

That's because 2 **is** a primitive integer - not an object of type `Integer`.

Autoboxing will only occur if no perfect match signature (with int) would be found.

And by calling with arguments `(Integer)3` you force the compiler into autoboxing your `int` `3` into an `Integer` object as well.